# Woocommerce Update Price Doesn't Save In Cart Session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I'm having issues in Wordpress Woocommerce whereby I have programmatically updated prices of products based on whatever conditions they need. Below is a simple example.  I have it displaying and then adding to the cart just fine.   My problem is, when the user logs out and logs back in, the cart ends up returning the full prices of the product.   Either I'm updating the price incorrectly, or there is a better way to ensure the cart has the correct discounted price.

Here is what I have in functions.php

```
  add_action('woocommerce_get_price_html','pricechanger');  
  function pricechanger($price){
      $theid = get_the_ID();
      $product = wc_get_product($theid);
      $price = $product->price;
      $price = //do something to the price here

      //save the productid/price in session for cart
      $_SESSION['pd']['$theid'] = $price;

      add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10, 2);
      add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_action', 10);
      add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_checkout_action', 10 );

      return $price;

  }
```

Because the price wouldn't transition to the add to cart button, I've had to save them in a session. I haven't found anywhere that sends that price to the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_add_discount');
function woo_add_discount() {

    if(isset($_SESSION['pd'])) {   
     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      foreach($_SESSION['pd'] as $key => $val) {
        if($cart_item['data']->id == $key){
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($val);
        }
       }
     }
    } 

}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: uggg my only solution seems to be to kill the cart on session end.  Hopefully someone has an answer to this!  I'd really like folks to keep their cart data/customized prices after logging out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post my concluded answer here.

You need to run these hooks against your price change code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'your_function_here');
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 'your_function_here');
function your_function_here(){

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 

       //do something to your price here
       $price = 'some calculation here';

       //set your price
       $cart_item['data']->price = floatval($price);

    }

}
```

Hope that helps someone!